# OpenCL 1.2 gives -9999 error with valid kernel

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, nvidia, gpgpu

I have the following kernel:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_fp64 : enable
#include <kernel_dependencies/complex_operations.h>
#include <kernel_dependencies/integer_operations.h>

__kernel void execute(__global long *a0, __global long *a1, ulong vo0, ulong vs0_0, ulong vo1, ulong vs1_0) {
    const ulong i0 = get_global_id(0); 

    if (i0 >= 2) {
        return;
    }

    long s1_1; 
    s1_1 = a1[35+i0*-6]; // <-- PROBLEM IS HERE
    const ulong idx0= (vo0 +i0*vs0_0);
    a0[idx0] = s1_1 + s1_1;
}
```

Running this on my Telsa P100-PCIE-16GB with OpenCL C 1.2 gives me a -9999 error on `clWaitForEvents`. I have narrowed the error down, to being with the index into `a1`. I have tried to do:

```
s1_1 = a1[35];
```

instead, which works just fine (although it gives the wrong result). I have also tried with `29`, which is the only other outcome of the expression `35+i0*-6`. I have also tried various other configurations of the expression, that is the following all gives this -9999 error:

```
a1[(35 + i0 * -6)];
a1[35 + (i0 * -6)];
a1[35 + -(i0 * 6)];
a1[(-6 * i0) + 35];
```

If I put the expression into a variable, e.g. `ulong t = 35+i0*-6; s1_1 = a1[t];` I still get the same error. I am able to put a `printf` in between and verify, that the variable actually contains either `35` or `29`.

```
long s1_1; 
ulong t = 35+i0*-6; 
printf("%lu\n", t); // <-- This prints '35' first time and '29' second time.
s1_1 = a1[t];
```

What am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `get_global_id` returns a `size_t`, not a `const ulong`. Does your code work with `size_t i0 = get_global_id(0);`?

Comment: It does not. I believe `site_t` and `ulong` is the same on this platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We figured out what the problem was.

Given that `i0` is a `ulong`, it is unsigned. Multiplying it with `-6` will cause it to cast it upwards. `ulong`s seems to only be able to cast upwards to `floats` (which seems reasonable), so now we have `i0` as a float being multiplied by `-6` as a float. This ends up being a `float` type, which I can't index my array with, thus I get a "segmentation fault" or in this case "-9999".

Changing `i0` to `int` will cause it not to cast it, as `-6` and `i0` can now be multiplied.